# difference between vector space and fundamental matrix - ODE

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

The solution(s) of a system of first order differential equations seem to be contained in a vector space and as well in a fundamental matrix in the form of columns.

Could someone please explain a litlle more the difference between both. And/or correct my statement if wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions of an equation $x'=A(t)x$ for some $n\times n$ matrices $A(t)$ varying continuously with $t$ are of the form $x(t)=X(t)c$, where $X(t)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose columns form a basis of the (vector) space of solutions of the equation and $c\in\mathbb R^n$ is arbitrary. Note that $X(t)$ is never unique, although the vector space of solutions is uniquely determined.

Added:
In general the basis need not be orthogonal. What is above means that you have $n$ functions $x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t)$ (with values in $\mathbb R^n$) such that any solution can be written in the form $$x(t)=c_1x_1(t)+\cdots+c_nx_n(t)=\begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) & \cdots x_n(t)\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1\\ \vdots\\ c_n\end{pmatrix}.$$ and so you can take $$X(t)=\begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) & \cdots x_n(t)\end{pmatrix},$$ where each $x_i(t)$ is a column.

Comment: what do you mean by "form a basis of the vector space"?

Comment: Read it "are a basis of the vector space", if you want.

Comment: still not that clear. What should I imagine by that. That it forms kind of an orthogonal basis/reference frame in that space? (really no clue)

Comment: It seems that basis means the same as orthogonal basis. Didn't know that term. Could u correct me if my statement is wrong?

Comment: You stated that the FM $X(t)$ is never unique. I suppose that when dealing with initial value problems, this uniqueness is not true anymore. Is that correct?

Comment: The uniqueness is not related to initial value problems. For example, $X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix if and only if $2X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix. But $X(t)X(t_0)^{-1}c=(2X(t))(2X(t_0))^{-1}c$.

Comment: I really feel like a morron for asking: I understand what you wrote. But don't see how/what this proves? You just wrote that the multiple of some FM is a FM as well. So what?

Comment: You asked whether "this [non]uniqueness is not true anymore", I presumed since before you wrote "... is never unique".

Comment: Indeed, u r right, didn't write it correclty.=> You said FM $X(t)$ is never unique. Do u mean by that that there are multiple FM for a system of first ODE? if yes  => my question: when u have initial values for your problem, does this mean that u will only have one FM for your system?

(didn't understand how the example explains your statement)

Comment: The answer is "yes" (always, for any system). On the other hand, the answer to your second question is "no" (also never). The example with $2X(t)$ shows precisely this. On the other hand, the product $X(t)X(t_0)^{-1}$ is independent of the particular $X(t)$ chosen.